# How to set react-router Route component with flux property.

Tags: react-router

```
function getFluxComponent(){
  return <App flux={flux} />
}

render((
  <Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/" compopent={getFluxComponent()} >
      <Route path="login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="logout" component={Logout} />
      <Route path="about" component={About} />
      <Route path="watch" component={Watch} onEnter={requireAuth} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
 ), document.getElementById('example'))
```

I wanted to pass App component with flux property.
but I cannot set.
How to set flux property to App component.